# Saving a list of byte arrays (List<byte[]) with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, arrays, list, entity-framework

I want to save a list of bitmap images with Entity Framework. I read that I shall convert them to byte arrays so I did accordingly.

The class looks as follows:

```
public class ShootingLocation : LocationBase
{
    #region attributes
    public ParkingLocation ParkingLocation { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(16), Column(TypeName = "Binary")]
    public List<byte[]> LocationPhotos { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region constructors
    public ShootingLocation()
    { 
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I try to save it when the DbContext, it throws an exception. Any hit or alternative solution?

Comment: You cannot save a list of anything in a database. You need to create a table and put them there

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Not sure if I get you correctly: I am new with Entity framework, but my understanding is that the Framework takes care of this (creating the appropriate tables and relations)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store several photos per shooting location, you need a 1 to n relation in the database, i.e., you must have a second related class/table for photos

```
public class ShootingLocation : LocationBase
{
    public int ShootingLocationID { get; set; }

    public ParkingLocation ParkingLocation { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int PhotoID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public int ShootingLocationID { get; set; }
    public ShootingLocation ShootingLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes: Sure - but that should be a function of Entity Framework - right? That works perfect even for many-to-many relationships for other data types - I assume that the reason it does not work is the byte array...

Comment: No. The reason it does not work is the list of byte array. Byte array alone works. A list of another entity class works also. So, the solution is to create a dedicated class for photos and to add it a byte array property for the image. Then you can add a collection of photos to a shooting location. The `ShootingLocation` and the `Photo` must then be present as data sets in the DbContext.